# Laravel: Target class does not exist. But it does

Tags: php, laravel, class

I've searched for answers, but mostly the problem was a typo in class or a controller.

In my case everything is spelled properly.  **Class** in **app\Http\Controllers\GenerateTextController.php**:

```
<?php 
      namespace App\Http\Controllers;

      class generateText extends Controller
      {
           public function generate()
           {
              dd('success');
           }
      }
```

then I try to inject it into blade. **home.blade.php** :

```
  @inject ('generate', 'App\Http\Controllers\GenerateTextController')
  @dd($generate)
```

Result:

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\GenerateTextController] does not exist.
```

I have already composer autoloaded couple of times, artisan cache cleared, nothing helps. I can't even find a closest solution in web.

*Interesting thing: When I try `dd` on the other class, that was, how to say, "predefined" by Laravel - it shows the class. And my second custom class can be viewed in browser with such injection.*

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `class generateText extends Controller` is  not `GenerateTextController`.

Comment: "In my case everything is spelled properly." [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/), [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) ([or in general all of those](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)), [Laravel good practice of naming convention](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class file name is `app\Http\Controllers\GenerateTextController.php` but the class name is `generateText`, that's the problem. The class name and the file name should match. This is how, `PSR-4` autoloader works.

From the Specification:

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php.
>   The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

So the class name should be like:

```
class GenerateTextController extends Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Read about [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloader to understand it.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about this moment.

Answer (score 2):

Classes file name should be the same as the PHP class name.

```
class GenerateTextController extends Controller
```